# show that $-0 = 0$ in any vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Show that $-\vec{0} = \vec{0}$ in any vector space.

I know this is a seemingly obvious statement but is the following justification correct:

Assume $-\vec{0} \neq \vec{0}$.

$$(4): \vec{u} + \vec{0} = \vec{u}$$
$$ \vec{u} + \vec{0} + (-\vec{0}) = \vec{u} + (-\vec{0})$$
$$(5): \vec{u} -\vec{u} + \vec{0} + (-\vec{0}) = \vec{u} - \vec{u} + (-\vec{0})$$
$$(5): \vec{0} + (-\vec{0}) =  (-\vec{0}) \rightarrow -\vec{0} + \vec{0} =  \vec{0}$$

Hence we clearly see that $-\vec{0} = \vec{0}$ QED Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: Seems that you are proving this using strictly only the axioms defining vector spaces, so you should be careful when you write the sum of three or more vectors. From $u+0 = u$ it follows $(u + 0) + (-0) = u + (-0)$, strictly speaking.

Comment: If you need to prove it from the first principle, I think you shall list all the axioms and definitions. In particular, you need to give the definition of the vector $-\vec0$.

Comment: I would make a couple comments - firstly, the "assume ${-0\neq 0}$" part at the start is redundant, since your proof isn't a proof by contradiction. Also, as jjagmath and mrsamy said - I think you need to be a little more careful in defining your terms. That being said - I don't think there is anything wrong with your proof, although it's a little overcomplicated (but is valid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align} 
-\vec{0} &= -\vec{0}  + \vec 0 &(\vec 0 \text{  is additive identity)} \\ 
&= \vec 0 &\text{(property of additive inverse)}\\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

By definition (axiom of the inverse element), $-\vec 0$ is a vector such that
$$
\vec 0+(-\vec 0)=\vec 0\tag{1}
$$
But $\vec 0$ is the additive unit of the vector space (axiom of the identity element of addition) and thus
$$
\vec 0+(-\vec 0)=-\vec 0\tag{2}
$$
Combining (1) and (2), we are done.